# Relaunch System Load Indicator?

Tags: installed-programs

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. How do I relauch the System Load Indicator program? Every now and then, it appears to crash and disappear from the top of my screen, and I have to log out and re-log in or reboot to relaunch it. I've tried to bring it up in Show Applications and relaunch it that way, but it never works.